# Android Robo Test no go deeper

Tags: android, android-layout, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I have a fairly simple UI for login that includes a TextInputLayout containing a TextInputEditText. For both a username and password.

The login button is disabled until the username is at least 3 characters and the password is at least 6.

I've specified in Firebase's Robo test console that the resources are:

username: "my_test_username"
password: "123456"

I've checked the id fields for these TextInputEditText. They're using

@+id/username and @+id/password

When I run the tests and view the videos, Robo never enters the test. The depth is set to 50 and the timeout is 5 minutes. The depth to get to this screen is only 1.

Comment: So, to be clear, are you saying that Robo is not filling in the widgets with the text that you're expecting?

Comment: If you add a comment here with a URL to the execution results in the console, the team can try to diagnose what might be going wrong.  Feel free to remove the name of your project from the path.

Comment: yes, Robo is not filling a TextInputEditText (sub-class of EditText)

Comment: Can you comment here with your execution results URL as I commented earlier?